# sample input signals and check their values VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have 2 `input` signals - `ID_1,ID_2` which sampled into `id_vec`.
`LEDx_GRNn` are `output`.
In this point, only one of `a,b,c,d` should be '1' and the others '0', which after should make only one led on and the others off.

For some reason all the leds are on so I'm guessing I do something wrong.
Waht am I missing?
ID_1,ID_2 have the constants values.

```
signal id_vec :std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
signal flag :std_logic;
signal a:std_logic;
signal b:std_logic;
signal c:std_logic;
signal d :std_logic;

id_vec(0)<=ID_1;
id_vec(1)<=ID_2;

a <='1' when id_vec<="10" else '0';
b <='1' when id_vec<="00" else '0';
c <='1' when id_vec<="01" else '0';
d <='1' when id_vec<="11" else '0';


LED1_GRNn <=  not (a);
LED2_GRNn <=  not (b);
LED3_GRNn <=  not (c);
LED4_GRNn <=  not (d);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mean this:

```
a <='1' when id_vec<="10" else '0';
b <='1' when id_vec<="00" else '0';
c <='1' when id_vec<="01" else '0';
d <='1' when id_vec<="11" else '0';
--                 ^
--                 |
--       an easy mistake to make
```

you mean this:

```
a <='1' when id_vec="10" else '0';
b <='1' when id_vec="00" else '0';
c <='1' when id_vec="01" else '0';
d <='1' when id_vec="11" else '0';
```

It's an easy mistake to make.